# fold settings seem to screw up vim's pwd in certain circumstances

Tags: vim, folding

Vim associates some default working directory to opened files when I work on multiples files under different directories in a single vim windows.

I have traced back the problem to my fold settings as I found a `lcd` comment in the `.vim/view/` file relating to the problem files. When deleted the problem is resolved.

As an example consider my `~/opt/lib/python/peakdetect.py` file, its `~/.vim/view/~\=+opt\=+lib\=+python\=+peakdetect.py\=` contains the following line:

```
lcd ~/mnt/CASE\ STUDIES/amazon\ -\ employee\ access
let &so = s:so_save | let &siso = s:siso_save
doautoall SessionLoadPost
```

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Here's my `.vimrc` (.gvimrc only sets window size) options relating to the `fold`:

```
" save & load fold structure
 42 au BufWinLeave * silent! mkview
 43 au BufWinEnter * silent! loadview
 44 set fdo-=search "do not open close fold when matching
 45 set fdo-=block "do not open closed but when using z? commands
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What gets persisted is determined by the `'viewoptions'` setting. Unfortunately, there's no separate configuration value for the local working directory. It seems that Vim always adds the `:lcd` command when you've set a local one.

To work around this, either avoid creating views for windows that currently have a window-local directory, or you could post-process the generated view script to remove / comment out the `:lcd` line. The [session.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3150) plugins uses that approach for session files.

Answer (score 0):

```
set sessionoptions-=curdir
```

This setting also applies to views although the documentation doesn't say anything about that.